# Override Session Redirect URL timout Depends on User Type

Tags: python, django, session

**I have this variable set on settings.py:**

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = (
    config('SESSION_COOKIE_AGE', cast=int, default=1200)  # set just 1200 seconds (20 minutes)
)
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

**And I have these types of users:**

```
    ADMINS_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy("admin_user_login")
    COMPANIES_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy("company_login")
    INDIVIDUALS_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy("login")
```

**I need to return the user to his login page after the session expired, Is there a way to override the logout of the session in Django or handle it by middleware or any idea can help me with this?**